# Erro com o Spinner Livro

Tags: android

Repassei a Class que ele me manda assim que clico no erro, mas não consigo identificar ele. Alguém pode me ajudar? Desculpa o transtorno, sou novo no Android e no site, então não sei como preferem que eu poste.

```
package com.br.activity;

import com.br.adapter.spinner.DistribuidoraSpinnerAdapter;
import com.br.adapter.spinner.LivroSpinnerAdapter;
import com.br.controller.DistribuidoraCtrl;
import com.br.controller.LivroCtrl;
import com.br.dbHelper.ConexaoSQLite;
import com.br.model.Distribuidora;
import com.br.model.Livro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlteraDistribuidoraActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnADAtualizar; // Botao para salvar as alterações
    private Spinner spnADLivro;// Spinner contendo os livros
    private Spinner spnADDistribuidora;// Spinner contendo as distribuidoras
    private LivroCtrl livroCtrl;// Controller do livro
    private DistribuidoraCtrl distribuidoraCtrl;// Controller da distribuidora

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_altera_distribuidoras);

        // Inicializo os controllers
        livroCtrl = new LivroCtrl(ConexaoSQLite.getInstancia(AlteraDistribuidoraActivity.this));
        distribuidoraCtrl = new DistribuidoraCtrl(ConexaoSQLite.getInstancia(AlteraDistribuidoraActivity.this));

        // Crio o botão Atualizar
        this.btnADAtualizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnADAtualizar);

        // Crio o spinner Livro
        this.spnADLivro = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnADLivro);

        // Crio o spinner Distribuidora
        this.spnADDistribuidora = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnADDistribuidora);

        // Crio o adpater para adicionar a lista de Livros ao spinner
        final LivroSpinnerAdapter livroSpinAdapter = new LivroSpinnerAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.livroCtrl.getListaLivroCtrl());

        // Crio o adpater para adicionar a lista de Distribuidores ao spinner
        final DistribuidoraSpinnerAdapter distribuidoraSpinAdapter = new DistribuidoraSpinnerAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.distribuidoraCtrl.getListaDistribuidoraCtrl());

        // Adiciono um layout ao menu de dropdown do spinner
        livroSpinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Adiciono um layout ao menu de dropdown do spinner
        distribuidoraSpinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Seto o adapter ao spinner
        this.spnADDistribuidora.setAdapter(livroSpinAdapter);

        // Seto o adapter ao spinner
        this.spnADDistribuidora.setAdapter(distribuidoraSpinAdapter);

        // Adiciono listenner ao botao atualizar
        this.btnADAtualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Crio um Livro (o selecionado no spinner)
                Livro livros = (Livro) spnADLivro.getSelectedItem();

                // Crio uma Distribuidora (o selecionado no spinner)
                Distribuidora distribuidora = (Distribuidora) spnADDistribuidora.getSelectedItem();

                // Atualizo a Distribuidora do Livro
                livros.setLivCodigo(distribuidora.getDisCodigo());

                // Salvo o Livro atualizado com o novo Distribuidora
                if (livroCtrl.updateLivroCtrl(livros)) {

                    Toast.makeText(AlteraDistribuidoraActivity.this, "Livro " + livros.getLivNome() + " agora é distribuido por " + distribuidora.getDisNome(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    // Não consegui atualizar Distribuidora
                    Toast.makeText(AlteraDistribuidoraActivity.this, "Erro ao atualizar distribuidor!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // É o que acrescenta item no Menu.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.altera_distribuidora, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Erro:

> 10-30 13:59:26.184 2628-2628/com.br.activity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                  Process: com.br.activity, PID: 2628
>                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.br.model.Livro.setLivCodigo(long)' on a null object reference
>                                                                      at com.br.activity.AlteraDistribuidoraActivity$1.onClick(AlteraDistribuidoraActivity.java:77)
>                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)**

Comment: O erro indica que na linha `livros.setLivCodigo(distribuidora.getDisCodigo());` o `livros` é `null` e por isso não pode chamar o método `setLivCodigo`. Isso acontece porque não tem nada selecionado no `Spinner`, e quando isso acontece devolve `null`.

Comment: E como eu conserto isso? Isac

Comment: A forma mais simples é mesmo testar se tem algum selecionado com `if (livros != null) {` agora pode não fazer o que pretende, que já depende do objetivo especifico da aplicação

Comment: Tem um metodo passando if (livros != null), mas o objetivo especifico é o spinner puxar a lista de Livro do banco

Comment: Isac, tem algum lugar que possa me ajudar diretamente com vc mesmo? já to com a cabeça explodindo!

Comment: O problema é que o seu botão `btnADAtualizar` está a utilizar o Spinner `livros` sem ter a certeza que o usuário selecionou alguma coisa nele! Logo o mais correto (na minha optica que não estou dentro do que a sua aplicação pretende fazer) é não fazer nada! E por esse motivo tenha sugerido colocar dentro do `onClick` o teste para saber se houve seleção.